# Codeigniter Route to accept dynamic values

Tags: codeigniter-2, routes

I am trying to create a router which will take a dynamic value and forward it to the actual route. In normal case it would be like

```
$route['login'] = 'auth/login';
```

It is possible to catch a parameter before the `login` in the above parameter and pass it to as the first parameter to the actual route **?** like

```
$route['^(.+)/login$'] = "$1/user/login";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation<sup>[[docs]](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)</sup>. There is a very easy way to do this.

```
$route['(:any)/login'] = '$1/auth/login';
```

Answer (score 0):

Starx answer is correct but I wouldn't do that, as your first param will be your controller, and if you don't know what's in the dynamic value that's impossible to manage.

I would do :

```
$route['(:any)/login'] = 'user/login/$1';
```

This way, 'anything/login' would be redirected to your User controller, to the Login function with the parameter 'anything'.

Comment: though your thinking is right, but as he asked for the case and with his question I am assuming that he might be developing some portal kind of thing, in which he would have dynamically get the controller and login to it, he uses it or not I got the idea and I really liked it.